# how to store the values passed by html form as it is into mysql DB?

Tags: php, html, mysql, encryption, encode

i wonder how to store the values passed by html form as it is interms of format into mysql table. can anyone help me.

let me clear my question.
when the user enter his address in the text area like,

```
no:14,cross cut road,

XXX nagar,

Tamilnadu,

india.
```

and when this value is passed from a form and stored in mysql table, it'll displayed in a single line when i retrieved it in the next time, like

```
no:14,cross cut road,XXX nagar,Tamilnadu,india.
```

but i want to display it like the previous one like how they enter, in the same format.

can anyone help how to do this???

thanks in advance.

i've no idea to use any web editors. so i tried n2lbr function and got the same format. New line problem solved but now am facing the space problem. if i leave 10  spaces and wrote a text, it'll display the text only.. not the spaces. how to solve this??

Comment: Instead of textarea use some `WYSIWYG editor` and store its html in db .while retrieving show its html.

Comment: Textarea uses "\n" for line breaks which is not visible in HTML. Use nl2br($valueOfTextarea) function to convert "\n" to "<br />" and it should work...

Answer (score 0):

You should use a [wysiwyg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG) editor like [ckeditor](http://ckeditor.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
mysql_real_escape_string doesn't remove line breaks, it escapes them.
```

While displaying use

```
 nl2br for adding those line breaks.
```

Answer (score 0):

when you press enter in the text area the '\n' character is appended to your text and this character is stored in DB but when you read from the DB and want to visualize your text, you should consider that your component recognize the '\n' character, if it doesn't recognize newline character (i.e. '\n') then you should replace '\n' with html break (i.e. br) tag to show the new line in html.